# Is it “gel spray” or “spray gel”?

Tags: word-choice, word-order

I’ve come across products labeled **spray gel** and **gel spray**. I think they’re both correct. **Spray gel** means gel that is spray, and **gel spray** means spray that is gel. They refer to the same thing. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

In English, a *noun adjunct* is a noun used to modify another noun that comes after it. For example, a house cat is a cat that lives in a house, but a cat house is a house in which a cat lives. In this context, a **gel spray** and a **spray gel** refer to the same thing that is equally a spray and a gel, so either word can act as the noun adjunct. The order may be arbitrary or may be chosen for emphasis depending on the context.

**Gel** is the noun adjunct in **gel spray**, specifying what type of ***spray*** it is. We might use this order if we are comparing the gel spray to other types of spray, such as an aerosol spray.

**Spray** is the noun adjunct in **spray gel**, specifying what type of ***gel*** it is. We might use this order if we are comparing the spray gel to other types of gel, such as liquid gel.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, yes. They do.

**spray gel** is **gel you can spray on**.

**gel spray** is a **spray that has gel as its substance**.

There are other examples of this kind of thing in hair products or sun protection products, etc. I just can't think of one right now.

What form does the gel come in? It is a spray. A gel spray.

What form does the product come in? It is a gel that is sprayed on. A spray gel.